# Twitter widget only loads on first load (clear cache)

Tags: javascript, twitter, widget

I am using the twitter widget to display a twitter feed on a page.

The widget will load/display fine if the cache has just been cleared.  However, subsequent loads without clearing the cache will not load the widget, or throw javascript errors/warnings.

Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

site: http://thegoodfail.mberlin.icargarage.com/bio

---

EDITS/TESTING:

- if new TWTR.Widget({}) is called with a setTimeout() to wait an arbitrary period of time, the entire page is replaced with the widget, and it works.
- when the cache is cleared, adn the twitter widget works on first load, the user name does not appear in the widget.
- quickly reloading the page multiple times causes the twitter widget to load correctly.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

modernizr.js was not playing nice with the twitter widget.
commented it out, and the widget works fine...still trying to find out why.

Answer (score -1):

this is because of Twitter`s rate limit, this is done to control the number of requests users make to their API, you can know that by simply pasting the url in the browser, you will see

```
TWTR.Widget.receiveCallback_1({"error":"Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per hour.","request":"\/1\/statuses\/user_timeline.json?screen_name=icarmagic&callback=TWTR.Widget.receiveCallback_1&include_rts=true&count=1&clientsource=TWITTERINC_WIDGET&include_entities=true&1330622972395=cachebust"})
```

Comment: Not sure why it would work when i clear my cache...i wouldn't think their API rate uses cookies.

Comment: after some testing -- i think it's a javascript load order issue.